# Randomly change Windows Desktop Theme

Tags: windows-10, desktop, themes, background

I enjoy using Themes for my windows 10 desktop background. But each theme only has (roughly) 10 - 20 images and I get bored with the repeats quickly. I'd like to have Windows randomly change the current theme each morning.

Is there a way to do this in settings, with a script or batch file, or using code?

Comment: Do you use the themes just for the background images, or also because it changes the colors, mouse pointer, sounds etc? If its just the background images and colors, you can simply create a new theme, copy all the backgrounds into one folder, set that folder as your background folders folder, set randomize option optionally, and with colors, set: select color accent based on background image. Then activate that theme and you have what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Windows doesn't have such an option, so a third-party product is required.

Here are some applications to start the fun.
All are freemium with both free and paid versions.
These apps will change your Windows 10 PC Desktop Wallpaper and/or
Lock screen automatically from a large collection of images,
some also with options for selecting among image types.

- [Dynamic Theme](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/dynamic-theme/9nblggh1zbkw?activetab=pivot:overviewtab)
  (Microsoft Store app)
- [Splashy](https://splashy.art/)
  (Currently lifetime license is at 70% off for Black Friday)
- [Artpip](https://www.artpip.com/)
- [Dinamic Wallpaper](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/dinamic-wallpaper/9nqqlfr4kf4j#activetab=pivot:overviewtab)
  (Microsoft Store app)